# Trying to search a subset of a search or search that all keywords are contained

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to build a search function where the search is inclusive of all the words in the search.  For example if I had 3 items:

The Red House
The Red Car
Home Garage for your car

In the search box (Which currently is dynamic as you type), if you type Red you would get the the first two above.  If I type Red, Car, I should only get line two, The Red Car, because that's the only one that has BOTH red and car in it.

I tried building an array of the search items then I have this for the search box:

```
     $scope.search = function(item) {
    var str = $scope.searchText;
    if(!str || str === undefined) {
        return true;
    } 

    if (!item || item === undefined) return false;

    var arr = str.toString().split(' ');
    console.log('ARRAY - ' + arr);
    var found = true;
    arr.forEach(function(element) {
        console.log ( "Element " + element.toString()) ;
         if(item.tags.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(element.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ) {
            console.log ("Tags " + item.tags.toString()) ;
            found = true;
            return true;
        }

        found = false;
        return false;
    });

    return found;
```

Right now with that code it's only giving me the results to the last word in my search... And if I delete and add words it doesn't seem to respond correctly.

Not sure how far off I am on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Array.prototype.every` to check that every word passes the test. You may also extract the lowercase tags before looping, so that it's not done on every loop unnecessarily:

```
const lowerTags = item.tags.toString().toLowerCase();
const arr = str.toString().split(' ');
const haveAll = arr.every(wordToFind => lowerTags.includes(wordToFind.toLowerCase()));
return haveAll;
```

If `str` is already a string, there's no need to call `toString()` on it (and similarly for `item.tags`) - might make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The following script contains an array of your searchable strings. When the function Search is called, it accepts a string as an argument. That string is split into array elements for the various words in the string. Then the function loops through each search term and compares it to each searchable item. If the item and term match, the term is pushed into a results array, which the function will return for you to use as you see fit.

```
<script>

searchableItems = [
    "The Red House",
    "The Red Car",
    "Home Garage For Your Car"
];


Search("Red");

function Search(searchTerm){
    results = [];

    searchWords = searchTerm.split();

    i = 0;
    while(i < searchWords.length){
        j = 0;
        while(j < searchableItems.length){

            if(searchableItems[j].indexOf(searchWords[i]) > -1){

                results.push(searchableItems[j]);
            }

            j++;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return results;
}

</script>
```